I cannot get out of Sleep and Hibernate mode with Uperfect dual monitor
I just bought an Uperfect Dual monitor which is great only they don't handle sleep and hibernate mode well.
After putting the PC to sleep mode (via the Power button) it works and wakes up pretty well if I wake the computer up within a few minutes.
But if I let it on Sleep mode for some time it doesn't wake up and I have to force a full restart. Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a cure?
Thank you.

Has your driver installed as described here? If not, you may install the driver as described here.

Thank you for your reply. I think everything went normally (that is as described in the manual) when I installed it the first time, but I'll double check. Globally it works fine, it's only the sleep and Hibernate mode that is not handled correctly.

If the problem continues after the updates are done, this could be a driver problem or a firmware problem, but there isn't much you can do except updating to the latest versions. You could also try to contact Uperfect Support, as they might have some more knowledgeable advice.
